# php paypal - Is email and password valid?

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal's php API.

I want user to login into paypal to check the credentials, If user successfully authenticate, I want to save the email into the database.

Is this functionality possible with Paypal's API. Any help would  be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal has a product for exactly this: It's called Log In with PayPal.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/

This directs the user to PayPal to log in; after successful login the user is returned, along with an identity token which you can (are encouraged/expected to!) use as a key for your user session.

The PayPal session this establishes can then be used to initiate a PayPal payment (if, for example, the user then shops on your site and is ready to pay you). Or you can send the user to agree to a billing agreement for future payments, etc etc. In short, you have many options if you want to move from "just" identity into checking ability to pay, agreeing to pay or to make future payments, etc.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not. Only within an abonnement payment, you can redirect your users to PayPal and get their data.

Comment: Is there any way to verify the email only?

Comment: You can just cancel this abonnement afterwards, but then you customers will wonder about. You can force your customers to send a very low amount to you for verification purposes (and you just can cancel it). PayPal do not worry about this.

Comment: Abonnement doesn't look like a good idea. Any other way apart from abonnement?

Comment: @Kanav: Please read my comment. You can request your customers to send a small amount and send it back afterwards.